# How can I make the checkboxes I currently have, appear the same in all other browsers as they are in chrome?

Tags: css, browser, checkbox

This is currently the style of the checkboxes:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    transform: scale(2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
    border-radius:0px;
}
```

But they do not match all browsers though.

Comment: Why would you expect them too? `-webkit` is a vendor prefix. Not all browsers run on the _webkit_ engine. Web controls are notoriously hard to style consistently across browsers using only CSS. There's a lot of hacks you can find that will do the trick though...

Comment: use images&css to be all the same

Comment: Divern is right that if you really want to lock this down, you'll probably have to use third party components instead of native browser functionality.  But I'd recommend you consider *why* you need to do this.  It still won't fully solve browsers rendering differently than each other.  Why re-build what exists natively?  Plus people familiar with their favorite browsers have certain expectations about the way controls should look and behave.  There's value in continuing to deliver it to them.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem I encountered when I first started. Different browsers and operating systems tend to render checkboxes differently. If you want to get an universal look, I recommend using a skin. I recommend using the jquery plugin called iCheck.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Christian, yes it does provide an answer.

Comment: It would be beneficial to provide an example of how to use iCheck.